# Выравнивание структур для целевой платформы - x64

Tags: c#, c++, struct, marshal

Возникла проблема с выравниванием структур. Есть код (не мой, данный код компилируется под x64) на C++:

```
#ifndef ETS2_TELEMETRY_COMMON_HPP
#define ETS2_TELEMETRY_COMMON_HPP

// This file contains "Common definitions" for this ETS2 telemetry plug-in.
// This includes:
// - Debug logging detail options
// - Shared memory map struct layout
// - [..]

#define ETS2_PLUGIN_REVID                   5

#define ETS2_PLUGIN_LOGGING_ON              0
#define ETS2_PLUGIN_LOGGING_SHAREDMEMORY    0
#define ETS2_PLUGIN_FILENAME_PREFIX "C:\ets2telem_"

#if ETS2_PLUGIN_LOGGING_ON == 1
#define SDK_ENABLE_LOGGING
#endif

#define ETS2_PLUGIN_MMF_NAME TEXT("Local\\SimTelemetryETS2")
#define ETS2_PLUGIN_MMF_SIZE (16*1024)

#define TRUCK_STRING_OFFSET 15*1024
#define TRAILER_STRING_OFFSET TRUCK_STRING_OFFSET+64

typedef struct ets2TelemetryMap_s
{
    unsigned int time;
    unsigned int paused;


    struct
    {
        unsigned int ets2_telemetry_plugin_revision;
        unsigned int ets2_version_major;
        unsigned int ets2_version_minor;
    } tel_revId;

    // All variables per revision are packed into 1 struct.
    // Newer revisions must contain identical struct layouts/lengths, even if variabeles become deprecated.
    // Replaced/new variabeles should be added in seperate structs
    struct
    {
        bool engine_enabled;
        bool trailer_attached;

        // vehicle dynamics
        float speed;

        float accelerationX;
        float accelerationY;
        float accelerationZ;

        float coordinateX;
        float coordinateY;
        float coordinateZ;

        float rotationX;
        float rotationY;
        float rotationZ;

        // drivetrain essentials
        int gear;
        int gears;
        int gearRanges;
        int gearRangeActive;

        float engineRpm;
        float engineRpmMax;

        float fuel;
        float fuelCapacity;
        float fuelRate;             // ! Not working
        float fuelAvgConsumption;

        // user input
        float userSteer;
        float userThrottle;
        float userBrake;
        float userClutch;

        float gameSteer;
        float gameThrottle;
        float gameBrake;
        float gameClutch;

        // truck & trailer
        float truckWeight;
        float trailerWeight;

        int modelType[2];
        int trailerType[2];         // ! deprecated

    } tel_rev1;

    struct
    {
        long time_abs;
        int gears_reverse;

        // Trailer ID & display name
        float trailerMass;
        char trailerId[64];
        char trailerName[64];

        // Job information
        int jobIncome;
        int time_abs_delivery;
        char citySrc[64];
        char cityDst[64];
        char compSrc[64];
        char compDst[64];

    } tel_rev2; 

    struct
    {
        int retarderBrake;
        int shifterSlot;
        int shifterToggle;
        int fill;

        bool cruiseControl;
        bool wipers;

        bool parkBrake;
        bool motorBrake;

        bool electricEnabled;
        bool engineEnabled;

        bool blinkerLeftActive;
        bool blinkerRightActive;
        bool blinkerLeftOn;
        bool blinkerRightOn;

        bool lightsParking;
        bool lightsBeamLow;
        bool lightsBeamHigh;
        bool lightsAuxFront;
        bool lightsAuxRoof;
        bool lightsBeacon;
        bool lightsBrake;
        bool lightsReverse;

        bool batteryVoltageWarning;
        bool airPressureWarning;
        bool airPressureEmergency;
        bool adblueWarning;
        bool oilPressureWarning;
        bool waterTemperatureWarning;

        float airPressure;
        float brakeTemperature;
        int fuelWarning;
        float adblue;
        float adblueConsumption;
        float oilPressure;
        float oilTemperature;
        float waterTemperature;
        float batteryVoltage;
        float lightsDashboard;
        float wearEngine;
        float wearTransmission;
        float wearCabin;
        float wearChassis;
        float wearWheels;
        float wearTrailer;
        float truckOdometer;
        float cruiseControlSpeed;

        // General info about the truck etc;
        char truckMake[64];
        char truckMakeId[64];
        char truckModel[64];


    } tel_rev3;

    struct
    {
        float speedLimit;
        float routeDistance;
        float routeTime;
        float fuelRange;
        float gearRatiosForward[24];
        float gearRatiosReverse[8];
        float gearDifferential;
        int gearDashboard;
    } tel_rev4; // added in sdk1.5

    struct
    {
        bool onJob;
        bool jobFinished;
    } tel_rev5;

} ets2TelemetryMap_t;

#endif
```

И есть следующий код на C# (тоже не мой) который получает данную структуру.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public unsafe struct Ets2SdkData
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public uint time;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public uint paused;

        [FieldOffset(8)]
        public uint ets2_telemetry_plugin_revision;
        [FieldOffset(12)]
        public uint ets2_version_major;
        [FieldOffset(16)]
        public uint ets2_version_minor;

        //***** REVISION 1 ****** //


        [FieldOffset(20), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public byte[] flags;

        //vehicle dynamics

        [FieldOffset(24)]
        public float speed;
        [FieldOffset(28)]
        public float accelerationX;
        [FieldOffset(32)]
        public float accelerationY;
        [FieldOffset(36)]
        public float accelerationZ;


        [FieldOffset(40)]
        public float coordinateX;
        [FieldOffset(44)]
        public float coordinateY;
        [FieldOffset(48)]
        public float coordinateZ;


        [FieldOffset(52)]
        public float rotationX;
        [FieldOffset(56)]
        public float rotationY;
        [FieldOffset(60)]
        public float rotationZ;

        //drivetrain essentials

        [FieldOffset(64)]
        public int gear;
        [FieldOffset(68)]
        public int gears;
        [FieldOffset(72)]
        public int gearRanges;
        [FieldOffset(76)]
        public int gearRangeActive;

        [FieldOffset(80)]
        public float engineRpm;
        [FieldOffset(84)]
        public float engineRpmMax;

        [FieldOffset(88)]
        public float fuel;
        [FieldOffset(92)]
        public float fuelCapacity;
        [FieldOffset(96)]
        public float fuelRate;
        [FieldOffset(100)]
        public float fuelAvgConsumption;

        // user input

        [FieldOffset(104)]
        public float userSteer;
        [FieldOffset(108)]
        public float userThrottle;
        [FieldOffset(112)]
        public float userBrake;
        [FieldOffset(116)]
        public float userClutch;


        [FieldOffset(120)]
        public float gameSteer;
        [FieldOffset(124)]
        public float gameThrottle;
        [FieldOffset(128)]
        public float gameBrake;
        [FieldOffset(132)]
        public float gameClutch;

        //truck & trailer

        [FieldOffset(136)]
        public float truckWeight;
        [FieldOffset(140)]
        public float trailerWeight;

        [FieldOffset(144)]
        public int modelOffset;
        [FieldOffset(148)]
        public int modelLength;

        [FieldOffset(152)]
        public int trailerOffset;
        [FieldOffset(156)]
        public int trailerLength;


        //***** REVISION 2 ****** //
        [FieldOffset(160)]
        public int timeAbsolute;
        [FieldOffset(164)]
        public int gearsReverse;

        [FieldOffset(168)]
        public float trailerMass;
        [FieldOffset(172), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
        public byte[] trailerId;
        [FieldOffset(236), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
        public byte[] trailerName;

        [FieldOffset(300)]
        public int jobIncome;
        [FieldOffset(304)]
        public int jobDeadline;

        [FieldOffset(308), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
        public byte[] jobCitySource;
        [FieldOffset(372), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
        public byte[] jobCityDestination;

        [FieldOffset(436), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
        public byte[] jobCompanySource;
        [FieldOffset(500), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
        public byte[] jobCompanyDestination;

        //***** REVISION 3 ****** //
        [FieldOffset(564)]
        public int retarderBrake;
        [FieldOffset(568)]
        public int shifterSlot;
        [FieldOffset(572)]
        public int shifterToggle;
        [FieldOffset(576)]
        public int fill;

        [FieldOffset(580), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 24)]
        public byte[] aux;
        [FieldOffset(604)]
        public float airPressure;
        [FieldOffset(608)]
        public float brakeTemperature;
        [FieldOffset(612)]
        public int fuelWarning;
        [FieldOffset(616)]
        public float adblue;
        [FieldOffset(620)]
        public float adblueConsumption;
        [FieldOffset(624)]
        public float oilPressure;
        [FieldOffset(628)]
        public float oilTemperature;
        [FieldOffset(632)]
        public float waterTemperature;
        [FieldOffset(636)]
        public float batteryVoltage;
        [FieldOffset(640)]
        public float lightsDashboard;
        [FieldOffset(644)]
        public float wearEngine;
        [FieldOffset(648)]
        public float wearTransmission;
        [FieldOffset(652)]
        public float wearCabin;
        [FieldOffset(656)]
        public float wearChassis;
        [FieldOffset(660)]
        public float wearWheels;
        [FieldOffset(664)]
        public float wearTrailer;
        [FieldOffset(668)]
        public float truckOdometer;
        [FieldOffset(672)]
        public float cruiseControlSpeed;

        [FieldOffset(676), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
        public byte[] truckMake;
        [FieldOffset(740), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
        public byte[] truckMakeId;
        [FieldOffset(804), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
        public byte[] truckModel;

        // ***** REVISION 4 ****** //
        [FieldOffset(868)]
        public float speedLimit;

        [FieldOffset(872)]
        public float routeDistance;

        [FieldOffset(876)]
        public float routeTime;

        [FieldOffset(880)]
        public float fuelRange;

        [FieldOffset(884), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 24)]
        public float[] gearRatioForward;

        [FieldOffset(980), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public float[] gearRatioReverse;

        [FieldOffset(1012)]
        public float gearRatioDifferential;

        [FieldOffset(1016)]
        public int gearDashboard;

        [FieldOffset(1020)]
        public byte onJob;
        [FieldOffset(1021)]
        public byte jobFinished;


        public bool GetBool(Ets2SdkBoolean i)
        {
            if (i == Ets2SdkBoolean.TrailerAttached)
                return flags[1] > 0;
            return aux[(int)i] > 0;
        }
    }
```

Данный код на C#, работает, если в свойствах проекта выставлено целевая платформа - "x86", но если ее поменять на "x64" (что мне и нужно сделать), то при выполнении кода, сразу же начинаются ошибки типа:

> Не удалось загрузить тип "Ets2SdkData2"..., так как он содержит поле объекта со смещением 20, которое неверно выровнено или перекрыто полем, не представляющим объект."

Из описания ошибки, как я понял, что не правильно указан "**FieldOffset**" на всех переменных типа "**byte**[]".

Тут и встает вопрос, если для проекта с целевой платформой - x86, свойство "FieldOffset" везде задано правильно и программа получает все данные, то какой он должен быть "FieldOffset" в проекте с целевой платформой - x64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смещения полей в данном случае не зависят от платформы, ведь в структуре нет ни одного указателя. Но дело в том, что .NET по какой-то причине не разрешает работать с некорректно выровненными массивами в структурах при использовании LayoutKind.Explicit. Вам нужно либо использовать `StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)` и избавиться от явных смещений, либо включить unsafe-код и объявлять все массивы так:

```
[FieldOffset(20)]
public fixed byte flags[4];
```

---

Полный код:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static T ToObject<T>(byte[] structureDataBytes)
        {
            T createdObject = default(T);

            var memoryObjectSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));

            // Cannot create object from array that is too small.
            if (memoryObjectSize > structureDataBytes.Length)
                return createdObject;

            // Reserve unmanaged memory, copy structureDataBytes bytes to there, and convert this unmanaged memory to a managed type.
            // Then free memory.
            var reservedMemPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(memoryObjectSize);

            Marshal.Copy(structureDataBytes, 0, reservedMemPtr, memoryObjectSize);

            createdObject = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(reservedMemPtr, typeof(T));

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(reservedMemPtr);

            return createdObject;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] arr = new byte[2000];
            arr[0] = 1;
            arr[1] = 0;
            arr[2] = 0;
            arr[3] = 0;
            Ets2SdkData data = ToObject<Ets2SdkData>(arr);
            Console.WriteLine(data.time.ToString());                   

            Console.ReadKey();            
        }



    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1)]
    public unsafe struct Ets2SdkData
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public uint time;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public uint paused;

        [FieldOffset(8)]
        public uint ets2_telemetry_plugin_revision;
        [FieldOffset(12)]
        public uint ets2_version_major;
        [FieldOffset(16)]
        public uint ets2_version_minor;

        //***** REVISION 1 ****** //


        [FieldOffset(20)]
        public fixed byte flags[4];

        //vehicle dynamics

        [FieldOffset(24)]
        public float speed;
        [FieldOffset(28)]
        public float accelerationX;
        [FieldOffset(32)]
        public float accelerationY;
        [FieldOffset(36)]
        public float accelerationZ;


        [FieldOffset(40)]
        public float coordinateX;
        [FieldOffset(44)]
        public float coordinateY;
        [FieldOffset(48)]
        public float coordinateZ;


        [FieldOffset(52)]
        public float rotationX;
        [FieldOffset(56)]
        public float rotationY;
        [FieldOffset(60)]
        public float rotationZ;

        //drivetrain essentials

        [FieldOffset(64)]
        public int gear;
        [FieldOffset(68)]
        public int gears;
        [FieldOffset(72)]
        public int gearRanges;
        [FieldOffset(76)]
        public int gearRangeActive;

        [FieldOffset(80)]
        public float engineRpm;
        [FieldOffset(84)]
        public float engineRpmMax;

        [FieldOffset(88)]
        public float fuel;
        [FieldOffset(92)]
        public float fuelCapacity;
        [FieldOffset(96)]
        public float fuelRate;
        [FieldOffset(100)]
        public float fuelAvgConsumption;

        // user input

        [FieldOffset(104)]
        public float userSteer;
        [FieldOffset(108)]
        public float userThrottle;
        [FieldOffset(112)]
        public float userBrake;
        [FieldOffset(116)]
        public float userClutch;


        [FieldOffset(120)]
        public float gameSteer;
        [FieldOffset(124)]
        public float gameThrottle;
        [FieldOffset(128)]
        public float gameBrake;
        [FieldOffset(132)]
        public float gameClutch;

        //truck & trailer

        [FieldOffset(136)]
        public float truckWeight;
        [FieldOffset(140)]
        public float trailerWeight;

        [FieldOffset(144)]
        public int modelOffset;
        [FieldOffset(148)]
        public int modelLength;

        [FieldOffset(152)]
        public int trailerOffset;
        [FieldOffset(156)]
        public int trailerLength;


        //***** REVISION 2 ****** //
        [FieldOffset(160)]
        public int timeAbsolute;
        [FieldOffset(164)]
        public int gearsReverse;

        [FieldOffset(168)]
        public float trailerMass;
        [FieldOffset(172)]
        public fixed byte trailerId[64];
        [FieldOffset(236)]
        public fixed byte trailerName[64];

        [FieldOffset(300)]
        public int jobIncome;
        [FieldOffset(304)]
        public int jobDeadline;

        [FieldOffset(308)]
        public fixed byte jobCitySource[64];
        [FieldOffset(372)]
        public fixed byte jobCityDestination[64];

        [FieldOffset(436)]
        public fixed byte jobCompanySource[64];
        [FieldOffset(500)]
        public fixed byte jobCompanyDestination[64];

        //***** REVISION 3 ****** //
        [FieldOffset(564)]
        public int retarderBrake;
        [FieldOffset(568)]
        public int shifterSlot;
        [FieldOffset(572)]
        public int shifterToggle;
        [FieldOffset(576)]
        public int fill;

        [FieldOffset(580)]
        public fixed byte aux[24];
        [FieldOffset(604)]
        public float airPressure;
        [FieldOffset(608)]
        public float brakeTemperature;
        [FieldOffset(612)]
        public int fuelWarning;
        [FieldOffset(616)]
        public float adblue;
        [FieldOffset(620)]
        public float adblueConsumption;
        [FieldOffset(624)]
        public float oilPressure;
        [FieldOffset(628)]
        public float oilTemperature;
        [FieldOffset(632)]
        public float waterTemperature;
        [FieldOffset(636)]
        public float batteryVoltage;
        [FieldOffset(640)]
        public float lightsDashboard;
        [FieldOffset(644)]
        public float wearEngine;
        [FieldOffset(648)]
        public float wearTransmission;
        [FieldOffset(652)]
        public float wearCabin;
        [FieldOffset(656)]
        public float wearChassis;
        [FieldOffset(660)]
        public float wearWheels;
        [FieldOffset(664)]
        public float wearTrailer;
        [FieldOffset(668)]
        public float truckOdometer;
        [FieldOffset(672)]
        public float cruiseControlSpeed;

        [FieldOffset(676)]
        public fixed byte truckMake[64];
        [FieldOffset(740)]
        public fixed byte truckMakeId[64];
        [FieldOffset(804)]
        public fixed byte truckModel[64];

        // ***** REVISION 4 ****** //
        [FieldOffset(868)]
        public float speedLimit;

        [FieldOffset(872)]
        public float routeDistance;

        [FieldOffset(876)]
        public float routeTime;

        [FieldOffset(880)]
        public float fuelRange;

        [FieldOffset(884)]
        public fixed float gearRatioForward[24];

        [FieldOffset(980)]
        public fixed float gearRatioReverse[8];

        [FieldOffset(1012)]
        public float gearRatioDifferential;

        [FieldOffset(1016)]
        public int gearDashboard;

        [FieldOffset(1020)]
        public byte onJob;
        [FieldOffset(1021)]
        public byte jobFinished;        
    }


}
```

Comment: 1й вариант отпадает (потому что с таким вариантов все переменные получают значения либо 0 либо "null", не знаю почему), а второй вариант выдает ошибку: 

Невозможно упаковать тип "Ets2SdkData" как неуправляемую структуру; невозможно вычислить размер или смещение, имеющие смысл."

Такая ошибка появляется при: var memoryObjectSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));

Comment: @keinHerz а на какой конкретно строке кода выдает ошибку?

Comment: Сюда этот код не влезает. Поэтому, вот (11 строка): https://pastebin.com/gTk0ivHV

Comment: @keinHerz да вроде у меня ничего такого не наблюдается. Добавил полный код в ответ.

Comment: *"По какой-то причине"*?! Причина-то известная: указатель на управляемый объект (а массив именно таким и является!) должен быть выровнен.

Answer (score 2):

Чтоб работать с бинарной сереализацией надо гарантировать, что C++, будет генерить одинаковую структуру при любых опциях компиляции. По умолчанию, размер структуры не обязан совпадать с суммой размеров всех полей, т.к. все поля структуры выравниваются по своему размеру. Например, `int16_t` поле должно лежать по смещению кратному 2, `int32_t` - кратно 4 и т.д.

В твоем примере поля engine_enabled и trailer_attached имеют тип bool, что занимает по байту каждое, а вот поле speed имеет размер 4 байта и компилятор попытается его разместить со смещение 4 от начала структуры `tel_rev1`, т.е между двумя булами и флоатом будет дополнительная дырка в 2 байта.

Далее, типа int и long в разных архитектурах могут иметь разный размер, что нормально сериализоваться, замени их типы фиксированного размера, например, `int32_t`

Далее, чтоб быть уверенным что структура "не поплыла", надо вставить `static_assert` с проверкой размеров и смещений. Типа такого:

```
typedef struct ets2TelemetryMap_s
{
    ...
};
static_assert(sizeof(ets2TelemetryMap_s) == 1024, "error"); // И сколько там должно быть?
static_assert(sizeof(ets2TelemetryMap_s::tel_revId) == 12, "error");
..
static_assert(sizeof(ets2TelemetryMap_s::tel_rev4) == 152, "error");
static_assert(offsetof(ets2TelemetryMap_s::tel_revId) == 8, "error") // <-- проверяем что ключевые поля лежат по правильным смещениям
...
static_assert(offsetof(ets2TelemetryMap_s, tel_rev5.jobFinished) == 1021, "error")
```

После это, можно использовать бинарную сереализацию, про big-endian и litle-endian не забываем.

P.S. #pragma pack(1) не советую, дурная практика для данной затеии. IMHO

Comment: Это все замечательно, знать бы еще с++ )

Comment: @keinHerz Тогда сделай просто: замени все "int" и "long" на "int32_t", если заработает, то ок, если нет, то замени все "bool" на "int32_t". Но такие замены (bool на in32_t) могут повлиять на C++ код, если код писали "нормально", то должно сработать.

Comment: Хорошо, а с тимпами "char" что делать, на них тоже ведь ругается в коде C#: [FieldOffset(172), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 64)]
        public byte[] trailerId;

.В С++ коде это: char trailerId[64];

Comment: @keinHerz ничего не делать, должно работать, там вроде все массивы кратны 8, так что все должно быть ок. Если не сработало, то посмотри чему у тебя равен sizeof(ets2TelemetryMap_s) под x86 и под x64

Comment: Нет, такой вариант не прокатил. Все без изменений. Код который на плюсах - это библиотека, которая работает как SDK в игре.